# rocketchat-server snap running but not responding

Tags: ubuntu, client-server

**What I am trying to do**/**What have you tried in order to make it happen?**

I followed installation and configuration of ubuntu 17.10 snap "rocketchat-server" and "rocketchat-client": Now I want to connect them both.

I entered channel `--edge` to no avail!

I completely reinstalled rocketchat-server and rocketchat-desktop snaps to no avail!

**What results did you expect?**

I want to connect to my own server URLs, as happened earlier:
[RocketChat](http://leder.no-ip.org:8080) (please enter this link in rocketchat-desktop, error message `No valid server found at the URL` in case my server is down)

I even cannot configure and access 
[localhost](http://localhost:8080) (this link should work when entered in rocketchat-desktop)

The example server works fine here:
[example server](https://open.rocket.chat/) (please enter this link in rocketchat-desktop)

**What actually happened?**

Desktop gives error:
`No valid server found at the URL`

And mobile app says:
`Invalid server version`

Service is up and running with:
`sudo systemctl status snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy`

Rocketchat-mongo.service is down, why is this?
`sudo systemctl status snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo.service`

How do I connect client to server successfully, again?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think I removed the packages:

`mongodb-org-server`

`mongodb-org`

`mongodb-org-tools`

via apt and now `rocketchat-mongo.service` is up and running again!